# Is Socle of evey locally Noetherian module a direct summand

Tags: modules, noetherian, socle

Definition: An $R$-module $M$ is called *locally Noetherian* if, any finitely generated submodule of $M$ is Noetherian.

Question: **Let $R$ be a ring with identity and $M$ be a  locally Noetherian $R$-module. Is $soc(M)$   a direct summand of $M$.**

My attempt: Let $S=soc(M)$=sum of  simple submodules of $M$. Since each simple submodule is finitely generated $R$-module, by hypothesis, $S$ is a sum of Noetherian simple $R$-modules. Now, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prove it, because it's false. An obvious counterexample is $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ which is Noetherian, hence locally Noetherian, but indecomposable.

If you want a counterexample with a locally Noetherian module which is not Noetherian, take the [Prüfer group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ for any prime $p$. This is indecomposable as well.

Both examples are Artinian modules and the socle of an Artinian module is nonzero and never a direct summand except in the trivial case when the module is semisimple and finitely generated.

Comment: Thank You very much. This statement was used in a well known research article.

Comment: In fact, the socle is hardly ever a direct summand, since if it is, then the complement must have trivial socle, which is "rare".

Comment: @bipin The argument is clearly wrong. I'm not saying the result is wrong as well, because the module has very strong additional properties.

Comment: @bipin what article?

Comment: @rschwieb I don't know why the DOI has been removed: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2005.08.018 The proof using it is of Theorem 3.8.